# Problem with custom Taxonimies and nested menu

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

i have Custom Taxonomies using CPT-UI on WordPress and im trying to make the Menu Expandable based on County expanding into City, i have hierarchy Enabled on the CPT-UI but the Filter just shows all the names all as one menu

Heres the code for the actual menu

```
`$new_arr[$alllocation->slug] = array(
    'name' => $location_name,
    'country' => $country,
    'city' => $city,
    'count' => $alllocation->count,

<a href="javascript:void(0)"    class="trigger-search <?php if ($location ==     $alllocation->slug) {echo "active";}?>" data-key="location" data-value="<?php echo $alllocation->slug; ?>"><span><?php echo $alllocation->name; ?></span>`
```